# JSPDF pdf file not opening in adobe but opening in chrome

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Pdf file not opening in Adobe Acrobat Reader but opening in Chrome.
Here is my code:

```js
var date = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var imgMaleVsFemale = document.getElementById("MaleVsFemale").toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
var imgAge = document.getElementById("Age").toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
var imgHour = document.getElementById("Hour").toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
var imgAttensionTime = document.getElementById("AttensionTime").toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
var defaultLogo = new Image();
defaultLogo.src = "images/DefaultLogo.png";
var doc = new jsPDF('a4', 'pt');
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
canvas.height = 30;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#2A3F54";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
dataHead = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
//  doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.setFontStyle('normal');
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.addImage(dataHead, 'JPEG', 0, 0, doc.internal.pageSize.width, 40);
doc.setTextColor(255, 255, 255);
doc.text("DEMOGRAPHY REPORT", (doc.internal.pageSize.width / 4) + 60, 25);
//doc.text(document.getElementById("lblDateTime").innerHTML.trim().split("<br>")[0].trim(), 260, 25);
doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text("Date :" + date, 20, 60);
doc.text("Report Type : Daily", 20, 80);
//  if(strLogo != "" && document.getElementById("imgCustomLogo").src.toString().indexOf("NoLogo.png") == -1)
//  doc.addImage(customLogo, 'JPEG', (doc.internal.pageSize.width - document.getElementById("imgCustomLogo").clientWidth), 0, document.getElementById("imgCustomLogo").clientWidth, document.getElementById("imgCustomLogo").clientHeight);
doc.text(document.getElementById('HeadingMaleVsFemale').innerText.trim(), 70, 150);
doc.text(document.getElementById("HeadingAge").innerText.trim(), 420, 150);
doc.text(document.getElementById("HeadingHourly").innerText.trim(), (document.getElementById("Hour").clientWidth / 4) + 50, 370);
doc.text(document.getElementById("HeadingAttentionTime").innerText.trim(), (document.getElementById("AttensionTime").clientWidth / 4) + 70, 580);
doc.addImage(imgMaleVsFemale, 'JPEG', -120, 170, document.getElementById("MaleVsFemale").width * 0.75, document.getElementById("MaleVsFemale").height * 0.75);
doc.addImage(imgAge, 'JPEG', 200, 170, document.getElementById("Age").width * 0.75, document.getElementById("Age").height * 0.75);
doc.addImage(imgHour, 'JPEG', 40, 390, document.getElementById("Hour").width * 0.75, document.getElementById("Hour").height * 0.75);
doc.addImage(imgAttensionTime, 'JPEG', 40, 600, document.getElementById("AttensionTime").width * 0.75, document.getElementById("AttensionTime").height * 0.75);
doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("All Rights Reserved", 510, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
doc.addImage(defaultLogo, 'PNG', 500, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 45, 72, 24);
//doc.text(document.getElementById("divFooter").innerText.trim(), 220, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
doc.save(date + ".pdf");
```

Code executes in Chrome, but in Adobe Acrobat Reader it's showing:

> There was an error processing page. There was a problem reading this document(110).

Comment: Can you try commenting the font related lines and executing the code again? as googling for error code 110 gave couple of posts pointing to issue being with font. Also can you add the version of adobe reader that you are using?

Comment: Hey nick,thanks for your efforts but i am getting error in adding image i.e the default logo image  and that's the error

Comment: @JawadHussain were u able to fix it ?
I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

we just have to convert our image to url representation of image using toDataURL() and then use in jspdf
Heres the code

```js
 function getImageUrl(url) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.width = 72;
                img.height = 24;
                img.onload = function () {
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = this.width;
                    canvas.height = this.height;

                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 72, 24);
                    defaultLogo = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
                };
                img.src = url;
            }
```

getImageUrl("---path of image---");

inside pdfExport function insert

doc.addImage(defaultLogo, 'JPEG', 500, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 45, 72, 24);

Answer (score 0):

Update these links to your in file where your are using jspdf library, hopefully it will work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```