# How to properly use jsPDF 2.5.1 library

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want to convert to PDF a `<div>` that contains images using JS libraries locally, so I use the html2canvas library to convert from .png to base64 and jsPDF 1.5.2 from [here](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf), but when I tried opening the generated PDF on Adobe Acrobat it shows me the error 110: *There was an error processing a page Ther was a problem reading this document*, though it opened on the web browser (Chrome and Edge).

I looked for a solution and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222481/jspdf-pdf-file-not-opening-in-adobe-but-opening-in-chrome). It worked fine with v1.5.3, but then I found out that latest version was v2.5.1 on [jsPDf GitHub repository](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) and wanted to use it (latest the better... I think).

So I cloned it, used **jspdf.es.min.js** and ran into an issue: *`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof"`. Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".* But there was no **@babel** folder.

I tried installing it with node.js `npm install jspdf --save` and solved that error (and other with *fflate*) by changing the import URL and referencing those files on the HTML file.

```
import _typeof from './../../@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js';
import { zlibSync, unzlibSync } from './../../fflate/lib/index.js';
```

**or**

```
import _typeof from './../../@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js';
import { zlibSync, unzlibSync } from './../../fflate/lib/index.d.ts';
```

**Instead of**

```
import _typeof from '@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof';
import { zlibSync, unzlibSync } from 'fflate;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>pdf test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="./html2pdf/html2canvas/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.js"></script> 
    <script type="" src="./node_modules/fflate/lib/index.js" ></script>
    <script type="" src="./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js"></script>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button id="createPDF" >Generate PDF</button>
    </div>    
    <div id="toPrint" data-page="0">
      <div >
        <img src= "./image.png" >
      </div>

      <script type="module" src="./html2pdf.js"></script>
      
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**html2pdf.js**

```
import sizes from './sizes.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import {jsPDF} from "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.js"

document.getElementById("createPDF").addEventListener("click", () =>
{
        let content = document.getElementById("toPrint");
        
        console.table(sizes)
        const page = Number(content.dataset.page)
        console.log(page)
        let title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text
        
        let { PDFheight, PDFwidth} = sizes[page]
        PDFheight = Number(PDFheight)
        PDFwidth = Number(PDFwidth)

        let doc = new jsPDF()
        
        html2canvas(content).then((canvas) => {
            let base64img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        
            console.log(base64img)
            
            doc.addImage(base64img, 'PNG', 0, 0 , PDFwidth, PDFheight)
            doc.save( title + ".pdf")
    })
})
```

Also, I tried with **jspdf.es.js** and **jspdf.umd.js**. The thing is that when I solve those, other errors start to show up like:

- *`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.js' does not provide an export named 'jsPDF' (at html2pdf.js:2:9)`* (html2pdf.js is my program)
- *`Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5501/node_modules/fflate/lib/index.d.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.`*
- *`Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at typeof.js:11:1`*
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at index.js:6:1`
- `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at jspdf.es.js:51:8)`

I've tried including the CDN from [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jspdf) without success. I'm new to using JS libraries and want to gain experience working with GitHub and node.js How can I get started with this version of jsPDF?